# Pass route parameter with form submit ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am building an ASP.NET MVC 5 application (.NET 4.8) and I'm trying to pass an additional route parameter with form submit to a controller method.

Why am I doing it like this? In short, as it is a side note – I am setting up SSO in a multi-tenant system and have to keep the ID of the current tenant in the URL for the entire duration of the SSO login process. Or that's how I'm hoping to solve it, at least.

My form looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin/" + Request.Url.Segments[Request.Url.Segments.Length - 1], "AccountSSO", new { ReturnUrl = "" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div id="socialLoginList">
            <p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="provider" value="OpenIdConect" title="SSO Login">SSO Login</button>
                

            </p>
        </div>
    }
```

Pay attention to URL construction in `Html.BeginForm` – the tenant ID is the route parameter.

Now, my controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(int tenantId)
{    
    // Request a redirect to the external login provider
    var res = new ChallengeResult("OpenIdConnect", Url.Action($"ExternalLoginCallback/{tenantId}", "AccountSSO"));
    return res;
}
```

This doesn't work. I get the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'tenantId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ExternalLogin(Int32)' in 'MyProject.Controllers.AccountSSOController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.  Parameter name: parameters

These are the last three routes registered in **Global.asax**, so I don't think it is a more general routing problem, but I'll paste them here just in case:

```
// default route
var defaults = new RouteValueDictionary();
routes.Add("Default", new Route("api/{controller}/{action}", defaults, new RouteDefaultHandler()));

// default route with param
var defaultsWithParam = new RouteValueDictionary();
routes.Add("DefaultWithParam", new Route("api/{controller}/{action}/{param}", defaultsWithParam, new RouteDefaultHandler()));

//catch-all route
var notFoundDefaults = new RouteValueDictionary();
notFoundDefaults.Add("controller", "DefaultPage");
notFoundDefaults.Add("action", "Show");
routes.Add("DefaultPage", new Route("{*url}", notFoundDefaults, new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

I'm also keen on keeping the form submission instead of some kind of an action link because of the anti-forgery token.

Any ideas how to pass this route parameter to the POST method?

Comment: Have you tried  new { ReturnUrl = "" ,tenantid=XXX}) then tenantid will bind to the param. Also would probably suggest keeping tenantid in Session which might make it more accessible to other parts of the system.

Comment: @AliK as I said, I need to keep that parameter in the URL. Also, I need it to be a route parameter, not a query string.

Comment: [This](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/custom-route-constraints-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/) might help.

Comment: In the end, I had to register another route in Global.asax, for that concrete Controller and Action.